# How do I create a coupon code in spree commerce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

There is a "coupon code" field in a default installation of a spree commerce shop.
I do, however, fail to find any means to create the according codes in the admin backend.

How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Promotions section in the Spree admin area.  You can add a coupon code there:

[image]